# How to split tensorflow's cnn model by column and train it in small batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am  having a large training model with 59536 column and 200 lines that I want to train using tensorflow's cnn but I am facing the `OutOfMemory` error. How can I split my model (split it in smaller column) and train it in a small batches?
Here is my code

```
# Create the Estimator
  mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
  model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="path/to/model")

# Load the data
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
  x={"x": np.array(training_set.data)},
  y=np.array(training_set.target),
  num_epochs=None,
  batch_size=5, # I added this option but it seems to split my model by lines, I need to split it by column
  shuffle=True)

# Train the model
  mnist_classifier.train(
  input_fn=train_input_fn,
  steps=100,
  hooks=[logging_hook])
```

Comment: Maybe transposing x?

Comment: it is a good remark, but I am using 200 lines just in the first step after that it will be more than 20 000 lines so even transposing the matrix will not solve the problem

Comment: Some keras models already accept training by batch. You could use the fit_generator method to train by batches... check it out, I'll elaborate an answer later if it helped

Comment: @Abdou so, by split by "column" what do you exactly mean? How many elements are in your dataset (59k)?

Comment: @DarkCygnus, each element in my dataset contains 59K "characteristics", the number of elements doesn't really matter